# Finding $\iint_S {z \:ds}$ for some $S$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

$$\iint_S {z \:ds}$$

In this double integral above, $S$ is the part of a sphere, $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$, which lies above the cone, $z=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$. How can I calculate the above double integral.

Can someone help me to solve this? I got $\frac{\pi}{3\sqrt{2}}$ as my answer. Can someone verify this

Comment: z is a density. we must have a triple  rather than a double integral over S since it is three dimensional region and you want to find the mass.

Comment: @Adelafif That is not at all true.  This integral finds the $z$-centroid of this part of the sphere, which is a 2-dimensional object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is actually best done in cylindrical coordinates.  Here when we let $x = r\cos\theta$ and $y = r\sin\theta$ we can rewrite our $z$-limits as $z = r$ and $r^2  +z^2 = 1$.  Note that when $z =1$ we have $r = 0$, and similarly when $z = r$ we get that $r^2 + r^2 = 1$ implying that $r = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$.  Therefore our integral can be written

\begin{eqnarray*}
\int_0^{2\pi} d\theta \int_0^{1/\sqrt{2}} \int_r^{\sqrt{1-r^2}}rzdzdr & = & 2\pi\int_0^{1/\sqrt{2}}\frac{r}{2}(1-r^2 - r^2)dr \\
& = & \pi\int_0^{1/\sqrt{2}}r - 2r^3 dr \\
& = & \pi\left (\frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{1}{4} \right )\\
& = & \pi\left (\frac{2}{8} - \frac{1}{8} \right ) \\
& = & \frac{\pi}{8}.
\end{eqnarray*}